# Adding dates by week produces wrong date. Why is this happening?

Tags: javascript, date, date-arithmetic

I made a small project with educational purposes (for myself). The project consists on calculating the number of weeks between dates or the start or final date depending on a given number of weeks. At any point, the user must input two of these values:

- Start date
- End date
- Number of weeks

At the beggining it worked, however after some tests I noticed it was throwing incorrect values. For example, for a start date 3/22/2018 (march the 22nd, 2018) and 28 weeks it would throw and end date 11/03/2018 (november the 3rd, 2018) which is wrong, but, if I calculate the number of weeks for a start date 3/22/2018 (march the 22nd, 2018) and an end date 10/05/2018 (october the 5th, 2018) it throws 28 weeks which is correct. Further inspection shows it only happens for dates starting from 04/01/2018 (april the 1st, 2018).

After some research I found out doing date calculations in miliseconds is better as some browsers do not support some date functions.

Nevertheless I would like to know if there is an explanation on this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
    function calcDates(){
        var startInput = document.getElementById("start");
        var endInput = document.getElementById("end");
        var weeksInput = document.getElementById("weeks");
        var startValidation = false;
        var endValidation = false;
        var weeksValidation = false;

        if (startInput.value != "") {
            startValidation = true;
        }
        else{
            startValidation = false;
        }


        if (endInput.value != "") {
            endValidation = true;
        }
        else{
            endValidation = false;
        }

        if (weeksInput.value != "") {
            weeksValidation = true;
        }
        else{
            weeksValidation = false;
        }

        //Calculate weeks number
        if ((startValidation == true && endValidation == true && weeksValidation == false)||document.getElementById("weekRadio").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("weekRadio").checked = true;
            var start = new Date(startInput.value);
            var end = new Date(endInput.value);
            weeksInput.value = Math.round((end-start)/604800000);
        }

        //Calculate End date
        if ((startValidation == true && endValidation == false && weeksValidation == true)||document.getElementById("endRadio").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("endRadio").checked = true;
            var start = new Date(startInput.value);
            var weeks = weeksInput.value;
            var end = new Date();
            end.setDate(start.getDate() + (weeks*7));
            console.log(start.getDate());
            console.log(weeks*7);
            console.log(start.getDate()+(weeks*7));
            console.log(end.toISOString().substring(0,10));
            endInput.value = end.toISOString().substring(0,10);
        }

        //Calculate Start date
        if ((startValidation == false && endValidation == true && weeksValidation == true)||document.getElementById("startRadio").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("startRadio").checked = true;
            var end = new Date(endInput.value);
            var weeks = weeksInput.value;
            var start = new Date();
            start.setDate(end.getDate() - (weeks*7));
            console.log(-weeks*7);
            console.log(end.toISOString().substring(0,10));
            startInput.value = start.toISOString().substring(0,10);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The statement "*doing date calculations in miliseconds is better as some browsers do not support some date functions*" is without foundation. Name one browser that doesn't support all the built-in ECMA-262 Date methods. Using the built-in parser like `new Date(startInput.value)` is a very bad idea, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Thaks for the observation on my lack of fundation.

I see the best way is to parse manually, however, after the answer given by cybersam it works just fine the way it is.

Comment: …until it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Date.setDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) "sets the day of the Date object relative to the beginning of the currently set month."

In the following snippet of code, `end`'s currently set month will start out being whatever month it happens to be *at the time the code is executed*. And `setDate` will set the new date value relative to the start of whatever month that is.

```
var end = new Date();
end.setDate(start.getDate() + (weeks*7));
```

In order to get the expected results in this scenario, you should use this code snippet, which initializes `end` to the `startInput.value` time (which will include the correct month):

```
var end = new Date(startInput.value);
end.setDate(start.getDate() + (weeks*7));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tested it on my page and it works like a charm :)